# Yii2 advanced login from the same view to frontend and backend

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-validation

I've got a question about Yii2. It is possible to login from frontend and be redirected to backend if login user is admin ?

I've got two configured localhost addresses like: 
www.test.loc/   <-- this is path to frontend/web
www.admintest.loc <-- this ist path to backend/web

And when user is trying to login on frontend www.test.loc/ and if he is a admin I want to redirect him to backend and login there on www.admintest.loc/

I will appreciate every answer to solve this question.

(P.S. I thought that common/model/loginForm.php can help but i don't know how to use it )

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried already.

Answer (score 1):

This would require checking the username in the `site/actionLogin` and then loading the proper `LoginForm` model from your common directory. If you find the username is equal to the admin username load the `common/models/LoginForm.php`, validate and redirect to the backend domain name.

If the LoginForms both reference `@app` you may need to change all namespaces of both `LoginForm.php` in `common` and `frontend`

Comment: Thanks, I did it just like that. I added role for user and during submitting login to page from frontend, I redirect user to backend url website ( Ofc if he is admin )